# How to run an additional process in a "while loop" within the Main process

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I want to create face detection code that will send an email when it detects a face in the video feed.  The email function needs to run in the background while the main function detects faces.

Before i tackle face detection i tried to get the email function to run in the background (after the save image function passes the image to email).  When i ran the code i got 2 Assertion Errors:

```
AssertionError: can only start a process object created by current process

AssertionError: cannot start a process twice
```

Here is my code (minus the gmail login)...

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime

import multiprocessing
import os

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

def send_email():
    email_user = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
    email_password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    email_send = 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com'

    subject = 'Surveillance Project'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    body = 'Hi there, sending this email from Python!'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

    filename='joe.jpg'
    print("[INFO] - " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " - Image name - " + filename)
    attachment  =open(filename,'rb')

    # create the attachment
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)
    print("[INFO] - " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " - Attachment Created")

    # set up connection
    print("[INFO] - " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " - Creating Email to Send")
    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    print("[INFO] - " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " - Setting up connection")
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user,email_password)

    # send email
    print("[INFO] - " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " - Email SENDING" )
    server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
    server.quit()
    print("[INFO] - " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " - Email SENT" )

def save_image():
    p1.start()
    print("ID of process p1: {}".format(p1.pid))
    p1.join()
    send_email()

def Main():
    # process IDs
    for i in range(30):
        print(i)
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("[INFO] - " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " - Email initated...")
            save_image()

        # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # printing main program process id
    print("ID of main process: {}".format(os.getpid()))
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=send_email)
    Main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initiating a subprocess `p1`, then starting it more than once. And you also run `send_email` twice...

Consider this code:

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def send_email():
    print("send email")

def main():
    for i in range(30):
        if i % 10 == 0:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=send_email)
            p.start()
            print("ID of process p: {}".format(p.pid))
            p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("ID of main process: {}".format(os.getpid()))
    main()
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  I got it to work.  I have never done threading or multiprocessing before so this helped a lot.  Now on to the face detection/ recognition part.

Comment: Glad if that helped, consider marking the answer as accepted if that helped you to solve your problem